# Magento 2 (v2.3) - Cart Page - Is it possible to get mage-cache-storage stored shipping amount in custom module plugin?

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

Is it possible to take the quote shipping amount in a custom module plugin when the user (tested with Guest User) is on the cart page? This should be possible for both guests and registered users.

I tried to get the quote shipping amount from the below class objects but the shipping amount is 0.

```
1. \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
2. \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository
3. \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory
```

It seems to be in this stage the shipping amount (selected/estimated shipping amount) is not stored in the quote table or checkout session but it is stored in the browser localStorage['mage-cache-storage']. I can see the shipping amount in browser localStorage['mage-cache-storage'] when I ran

```
JSON.parse(localStorage['mage-cache-storage']);
```

in-browser console terminal.

[image]

Any suggestions or thoughts will be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the mage cache storage via knockout. You can find a  usage of knockout to access **mage-cache-storage** from the below file. You can use this as a reference.

> /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Sathiyaprakash but I couldn't find out any related data in the phtml or its related block class magento/codepool/vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Header.php. If you can give more information with the sample code it would be really great! FYI - I would require to get the shipping amount in the plugin in this situation. In quote, I couldn't see it but I could see it in mage-cache-storage in the browser cache. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, have you tried to use the cart class from \(Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart), you can use the object manager to access it and make use of the getQuote() method.